# Finding the middle word in a string

Tags: c++

As the title suggests, I'm having trouble trying to grab the middle word out of a string, I believe my formula is wrong but I'm not completely sure where to from here to fix the issue, any help is always appreciated thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string sentence="";
     string middle="";
     string midtemp="";
     int count=0;
     int mid=0;

     cout << "Enter a sentence:" << endl;
    getline(cin,sentence); //gets user input

   
  for(int count =0; count<sentence.length();count++){
       letter=sentence.substr(count,1);

        int mid = sentence.length();
        if (midtemp.length()>middle.length())
           { midtemp=middle;}
         if (sentence[count]!=' ')
           { if(mid%2==0);
           reverse(longest.rbegin(),longest.rend()); //shows the word not backwards
           cout<<"Middle word is: " << sentence.substr(mid/2 -1) <<"\n" << endl;
           break; //presents info to user
           }
        else(mid%2!=0);
        { mid/2;
             cout<<"Middle word is: " << sentence.substr(mid/2 -1) <<"\n" << endl;
           break; //presents info to user if number is even
        }
       }
```

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question. What is the middle word in a string? Eg what is the middle word in `"Hello World"` ?

Comment: I don't believe that code works, it's not a wrong formula, it's just a misconcieved algorithm (as well as a number of coding mistakes). The way to solve a comple problem is to break it down into pieces. So try this, step 1 break the sentence into words. After step one you will have a vector of strings, each string being one word. Step 2 pick the middle entry from the vector. Now you have two problems instead of one, but each problem is easier than the original problem.

Comment: Yeah sorry about this bad post, I've abandoned this code and am restarting, thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

To find the middle word in a string with three words use:

```cpp
size_t begin_index = sentence.find(' ') + 1;
size_t end_index = sentence.find(' ', begin_index);
size_t length = end_index - begin_index;
string middle_word = sentence.substr(begin_index, length);
```

To find the middle word in a string with any odd number of words use:

```cpp
// create string stream from sentence
istringstream ss(sentence);
// split string stream into vector of words
vector<string> words(istream_iterator<string>(ss), {});
// get middle index
size_t middle_index = (words.size() - 1) / 2;
// get middle word
const auto& middle_word = words[middle_index];
```

If there are an even number of words, the result is either rounded up or down until C++11, after C++11 it is rounded down. (To the word before the middle space).

Comment: Nothing in the problem statement says there must be three words. You might be right of course, and the OP missed out that vital detail.

Comment: You are right, there is a middle word if there is 5 words and I never thought of that, let me rethink

Comment: "*the result is either rounded up or down until C++11*". Really? What changed in C++11? It should always have rounded down I think.

Comment: "The binary operator / divides the first operand by the second (after usual arithmetic conversions). For integral operands, it yields the algebraic quotient. The quotient is rounded in implementation-defined direction. (until C++11). The quotient is truncated towards zero (fractional part is discarded). (since C++11)`." - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  string input;
  getline(cin, input);

  vector<string> tokens;

  string token;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input[i];
    if (c == ' ' || !input[i + 1]) {
      if (!input[i + 1])
        token += c;
      tokens.push_back(token);
      token = "";
      continue;
    }
    token += c;
  }

  auto mid = tokens.size() % 2 == 0 ? tokens.begin() + tokens.size() / 2 - 1
                                    : tokens.begin() + tokens.size() / 2;
  cout << *mid;

  return 0;
}
```