# Trying to show the middle word in a string c++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with getting this code to work properly.
It's purpose is to show the middle word of any given sentence. If its an even amount of words, it shows the first word out of the 2. Instead of printing the middle word, it prints the 2 middle characters. I think its only a few small things I have to add, but I'm stuck on this roadblock. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string sentence="";
    string letter="";
    string middle="";
    int count=0;
    int spacecount=0;
    int mid=0;

    cout << "Enter a sentence:" << endl;
    getline(cin,sentence); //gets user input  
//for example, "hello there friend"

    for(int count =0; count<sentence.length();count++){
            letter=sentence.substr(count,1);

           if(letter!=" "){
            count++;
           }
           if(letter==" "){
            spacecount++;
           }
           if(count> mid){
            mid = count;
           }
          if (((mid = sentence.length() / 2) % 2) == 0){ //checks if amount of words is even
          middle=sentence.substr(mid,2);
          }
        if (((mid = sentence.length() / 2) % 2) >= 1) //checks if amount of words is odd
         {
                middle=sentence.substr(mid,2);
            }
            }
            reverse(middle.rbegin(),middle.rend()); //makes it so the word isnt backwards
            cout <<"Middle word is: " << middle  <<endl;
            //shows middle word to user
            //it should print "there", but it shows "he" (the two middle characters)

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_Instead of printing the middle word, it prints the 2 middle characters_" And what else do you expect `.substr(mid, 2)` to do, based on presumably having read its documentation? It takes a number of characters, not a number of words; it doesn't know how words are split. And even if you were isolating the middle word correctly, why would you need to reverse it? Suggestion: just search how to split a string into a `vector` of strings, then check its size, then print the `size / 2`th element. Job done.

Comment: Check out this answer I posted a few days ago see if it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64703901/2562287

Answer (score 0):

Lets split the string into tokens and find the middle object of it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  string input;
  getline(cin, input);

  vector<string> tokens;

  string token;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input[i];
    if (c == ' ' || !input[i + 1]) {
      if (!input[i + 1])
        token += c;
      tokens.push_back(token);
      token = "";
      continue;
    }
    token += c;
  }

  auto mid = tokens.size() % 2 == 0 ? tokens.begin() + tokens.size() / 2 - 1
                                    : tokens.begin() + tokens.size() / 2;
  cout << *mid;

  return 0;
}
```